# Boeing 737 Homework Problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, pressure, aerodynamics

[image]

I have done the above problem, but have come out with a rather large surface area. Could someone point out my mistake(s)?

**Given/Assumptions:**

I assume $\sum F_y=0$ because it's level and straight.

$$s_t=0.21s_w$$

where $s$ is the surface area, $t$ designates tail and $w$ designates wing.

Pressure hitting the top of the wing/tail will act downward. Pressure hitting the bottom of the wing will act upward.

$$
\begin{align}
0&=F_{w_\textrm{bot},y}+F_{t_\textrm{bot},y}-Fg-F_{w_\textrm{top},y}-F_{t_\textrm{top},y}=\\
&=P_{w_\textrm{bot}} s_w\sin(5^\circ)+P_{t_{bot}}s_t\sin(3^\circ)-mg-P_{w_\textrm{top}}s_w\sin(5^\circ)-P_{t_\textrm{top}}s_w\sin(3^\circ)\\
&=38.349s_w+4.616s_w-180000.1576-27.8898s_w-3.8467s_w\\
&=11.2285s_w-180000.1576
\end{align}
$$

Therefore, $s_w=16030.65\ \mathrm{ft}^2$ and $s_t=0.21s_w=3366.4365\ \mathrm{ft}^2$.

UPDATE: I changed my sins to cos as per the answer to get sw=1341 ft and st=281.61 and started to work on B. I am confused how to tell what direction the forces are working. Is it

0=$F_{w_{bot},x}-F_{w_{top},x}-F_{t_{top},x}+F_{t_{bot},x}+F_{f,x}-2*Ft$

?

If someone can check me: For A I get) wing=1341 ft^2 tail=281.61ft^2

And B I get Force of the fuselage=39543 lb

Comment: OP: I edited your question changing the images into actual formulas. Please, check that I didn't mess up anything, and click on the `edit` button to see how the math is used for future posts.

Comment: This seems to be a "check my work problem".

Comment: @dmckee How else to you show effort than to provide your work? Should I have just asked how to do the problem?

Comment: Showing effort has *never* been the criteria for topicality on Physics SE. And yes, I know there are commenters who suggest that it is, but they are in conflict with the policy as voted by the users. See  http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/5959 http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/5962 for the policy currently in effect and http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/7407 for the on-going discussion.

Comment: It's good that you showed work, but [that's not all](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange): "It's not enough to just show your work and ask where you went wrong. If you just need someone to check your work, you can always seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher. As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on."

Comment: "questions which show that standard calulation methods in the field are not sufficient to obtain the result should be considered on-topic, because then there is very likely a conceptual argument hidden in some step of this calculation" Just the formula I posted was not sufficient to get the answer. There was a flaw in my conceptual knowledge of pressure and trig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right to be skeptical of your answer. The [technical specs](http://www.b737.org.uk/techspecsdetailed.htm) show you should get something on the order of 100 m$^2$ .

Your problem lies in basic trig: the force of the pressure is normal to the surface, and the surface is tilted by 5° - this means that the vertical component of force will be $\cos 5°$ times the normal force - you used the $\sin$ which gives you the drag...

Regarding your second confusion - I would recommend simplifying the math by writing everything in terms of the difference in pressure ($\Delta P = P_{bottom}-P_{top}$) and in terms of the wing area. This gives the simpler equation

$$F_{lift} = \Delta P_{w} \cdot A_w\cdot  \cos 5° + \Delta P_t \cdot 0.21\cdot A_w \cdot \cos 3°$$

When $\Delta P>0$, the net force is up (greater pressure on bottom than on top); when it is negative, net force is down. The above can be rearranged to give the wing area directly.

Comment: Thanks I got 1341 ft^2 after I switched my sins to cos. This seems more reasonable (100m^2 ~ 1076ft^2). If you have time to check my answer I would appreciate it!

Comment: My second confusion has to do with the x components. But i believe P_bottom acts in the positive x direction and P_top works in the negative x direction for that as well

Comment: Yes - you just have to decompose the vector normal to the wing surface in the horizontal and vertical directions.